# Materialized Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If I have a sql query like this:

```
select *
into new_table
from
     (
          select * from table_1 union
          select * from table_2 union
          select * from view
     )
```

Would you call this a materialized table? What would you call this?

Comment: Is the `view` a custom view?

Comment: yes, it is a custom view.

Comment: What is the context of asking? Understanding a definition? Or solving a problem?

Comment: Understanding a definition. I want to make sure that when I use the terminology, I don't sound like a jackass by using it wrong.

Comment: In SQL Server one doesn't normally say the expression "materialized table". What you have is just a regular table. If the table name starts with `#` you have a temp table, if it starts `@` it's a table variable. There is something similar to a materialized view: it's called an indexed view. By the way, you should use `union all` instead of `union` unless you specifically want to de-duplicate.

Comment: Perhaps you are confusing your situation with the term "materialized view"?

Comment: I did some research on this.

https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3A+materialize&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS853US853&oq=define%3A+materialize&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.3346j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

This means give physical form to, so it looks like saying we are "materializing the table" is the accurate way to describe it?

Thoughts?

Answer (score -3):

If you are using Postgres if you do `\d` you will find that `new_table` is of type `table`

NOTE: For MySQL and Oracle, use `DESC new_table`

Sample result:

```
plsql> \d
                   List of relations
 Schema |     Name      |       Type        |  Owner
--------+---------------+-------------------+----------
 public | new_table     | table             | postgres
```